# Moving file from one folder to other in FTP

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, ftp-client, ftpwebrequest

I have an requirement to move files from one folder to other in ftp 
i used the below code block but getting following error

The remote server returned an error: (501) Syntax error in parameters or arguments.

```
 public void MoveFile(string source,string destination, string UserName, string Password)
    {
        FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = null;
        FtpWebResponse ftpResponse = null;
        try
        {
            ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(source);
            ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserName, Password);
            ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
            ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
            ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;
            ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.Rename;
            ftpRequest.RenameTo = destination;
            ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
            ftpResponse.Close();
            ftpRequest = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

can you please help me how to solve this issue.

Comment: Whats the value of source and destination

Comment: Aside from the error in question, you should change the parameter named 'souce' to the correct spelling 'source'.